# angular 2 2nd level routes don't working after bundleing using browserify

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular2-routing

All the routes work fine in my dev environment. But After I bundle my angular 2 app, the routes except the Home Route don't work

Here is my **app.routes.ts config**:

```
import { provideRouter, RouterConfig } from '@angular/router';
import {HomeComponent} from "./pages/home/home.component";
import {PageNotFoundComponent} from "./pages/page-not-found/pageNotFound.component";
import {TosComponent} from "./pages/tos/tos.component";
import {PrivacyPolicyComponent} from "./pages/privacy-policy/privacyPolicy.component";
import {AboutUsComponent} from "./pages/about-us/abooutUs.component";
import {SubmitNewsComponent} from "./pages/submit-news/submitNews.component";

// Routes Start
export const routes: RouterConfig = [
    {path: 'tos', component: TosComponent},
    {path: 'privacy-policy', component: PrivacyPolicyComponent},
    {path: 'about-us', component: AboutUsComponent},
    {path: '', component: HomeComponent},
    {path: 'submit-news', component: SubmitNewsComponent},
    { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];
// Routes End`enter code here`

export const APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS = [
    provideRouter(routes)
];
```

**package.json:**

```
 "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" \"compass watch\"",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "typings": "typings install",
    "postinstall": "npm run typings",
    "build": "npm run clean && tsc",
    "clean": "rm -rf dist",
    "build_prod": "npm run build && browserify -s app/main dist/app/main.js > dist/bundle.js && npm run minify",
    "minify": "uglifyjs dist/bundle.js --screw-ie8 --compress --mangle --output dist/bundle.min.js"
  },
```